# If $\langle Tx, y \rangle=\langle x, Ty \rangle $ then $T$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, closed-graph

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $T: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ where $\langle Tx, y \rangle=\langle x, Ty \rangle $ for any $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$.

As a hint, I am supposed to use the Closed Graph Theorem:

So let $(x_{n})_{n}\subseteq \mathcal{H}$ and $x_{n}\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} x$ and $Tx_{n}\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} y$. I need to show $Tx=y$.

The best that I could do so far has been for a null sequence, i.e. $x_{n}\xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ and $Tx_{n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} z$

note that:

$\langle z, z \rangle=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\langle Tx_{n}, z \rangle=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\langle x_{n}, Tz \rangle=0$

But this does not suffice as I need to show it for all sequences not necessarily with a limit $0$, correct?

Comment: if a linear map is continuous at $0$, it is continuous everywhere.

Comment: alternatively, you can do a translated version of the argument you gave.

Comment: I have not shown continuity at $0$ however, and I was not attempting to. I want to show that the graph is closed by showing if an arbitrary sequence $x_{n}$ that converges to an $x$ and its image converges to $z$ then $z$ is the image of $x$. Then the graph is closed, and since $\operatorname{dom}(T)=\mathcal{H}$ it follows that $T$ is bounded and hence continuous.

Comment: The difference to the continuity argument is that my limit of sequence of images already exists

Comment: Use linearity!!!! You have $x_n \to x$. So, $x_n-x \to 0$. And $Tx_n \to y$ implies $T(x_n-x) \to y-Tx$. Since you already have the closed graph result for $0$, you know $y-Tx = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\langle #1,#2\rangle}$

**Hint:** To show that $Tx=y$ it's enough to show that $\ip{Tx}z=\ip yz$ for every $z$.